# React-Native: Ref is missing scrollToIndex() for FlatList

Tags: react-native, ref, flatlist

I am passing a ref to a FlatList and expecting to access the scrollToIndex() function, but it doesn't appear in the console and it throws an error when I try to use it saying "scrollTo() is not a function", it doesn't even recognise that I'm trying to use scrollToIndex().

This is a simple example of usage in my code:

```
const ref = useRef()

ref.current?.scrollToIndex({index:itemIndex,animated:true})

<FlatList ref={ref} .../>
```

[image: console.log for ref]

Has anyone experienced this and knows how to make it work? I've looked over the documentation and examples and everything seems to be fine. Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, FlatList, ImageBackground,TouchableOpacity,ScrollView,StyleSheet, Text} from "react-native";


const Projects = ({ index, navigation }) => {
 const {width} = Dimensions.get("window")
  const [imageIndex, setIndex] = React.useState(0)
  const ref = React.useRef()
  const wItem = (width - 63) / 2;
console.log("index projects", imageIndex)


const scrollToIndex = (index)=>{
  if(ref.current){
    ref.current.scrollToIndex({index:index})
  }
}
 
const goToIndex = React.useCallback((info) => {
  const wait = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200));
  wait.then(() => {
    ref.current?.scrollToIndex({ index: info.index, animated: true });
  })
}, [])

  return (
  
      <ScrollView >
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> scrollToIndex(5)}><Text>Scroll to</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      <FlatList ref={ref}
      nestedScrollEnabled
        numColumns={2}
        data={DATA}
        onScrollToIndexFailed={(index)=>goToIndex(index)}
        style={styles.flatList}
        keyExtractor={(i, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <ImageBackground
              source={item.image}
              /* @ts-ignore */
              imageStyle={styles.imgStyle}
              style={{ width: wItem, height: wItem, alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
              
            </ImageBackground>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  
  );
};

export default Projects;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  item: {
    marginRight: 15,
    marginBottom: 24,
    alignItems:'center'
   
  },
  flatList: {
    marginHorizontal: 24,
    marginTop: 16,
  },
  imgStyle: {
    borderRadius: 12,
  },
});
```

const DATA = [//list of local images]

Comment: Not sure if this is correct but according to the docs, there is an `item` param. Try `{ item: {index: itemIndex }, animated: true }` and see if that does anything.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle Thank you for your answer. Tried but it behaves the same.

Comment: Was worth a shot, I'll try do some more digging, good luck! The docs for this aren't that helpful so I understand your frustration.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle thanks,I really appreciate it! The weird thing is that I can't access the function scrollTo() or scrollToIndex() through ref for the flatlist which theoretically should work, the docs just provide a brief overview of the parameters you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unable to call scrollTo because the ref has only been initialized and not assigned at the time of use:

```
const ref = useRef()
// ref = null

ref.current?.scrollToIndex({index:itemIndex,animated:true})
// ref = null    

<FlatList ref={ref} .../>
// ref != null
```

So ref is not assigned until you render  for the first time. This means that if you want to call .scrollTo() on the ref you can do it in 2 different ways:

1 - If you want to scroll to a certain index initially:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const initialIndex = 34 //random number
  if (ref.current){
    ref.current.scrollToIndex({index: initialIndex})    
  }
}, [ref])
```

The `ref` in the dependency array will make sure that the useEffect will run whenever the value of `ref` changes (in this case it will change once it is assigned to a value by rendering the `<Flatlist />`

2 - If you want to scroll to a certain index on demand:

```
const handleScrollTo = (index) => {
  if (ref.current && typeof ref.current.scrollToIndex === 'function'){
    ref.current.scrollToIndex({index: index})    
  }
}
```

This function should be connected to something like an onPress or similar, which means the `ref` should be defined whenever the user presses the button because being able to see the button and press it requires that the component has rendered. Even though ref.current should already be assigned once it is used here, it is always good practice to make sure that it doesn't crash in cases where it is not, which is why we are adding the if-statement.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions, the answer is very good and theoretically it should work, however I get the same error as before with a strange behaviour. If the index is < 5, it would throw the error:"this._scrollRef.scrollTo" is not a function, if the index is > 5:"scrollToIndex is out of range: requested index 8 but maximum is 5".

Comment: Weird, it seems you problem lies somewhere else, please include a bigger sample of your code, so we can properly debug it.

Comment: I've updated the post with an example.

Comment: I've updated my example of handleScrollTo to also check for `scrollToIndex` being a function. Aside from this I think you should try to remove `onScrollToIndexFailed` temporarily and console.log() the index in your handleScrollTo function to see what values it is actually called with. From the error message you get it seems that it is trying to call scrollToIndex(8) even though you only have 5 elements in the list.

Comment: Thank you for the support! I really appreciate it! Unfortunately it doesn't detect the function check as it continues to have the same behaviour as before. I've also tried with forwardRef from child to parent although it was more of a false hope, still the same. I don't understand what the problem is and I'm out of options. What other alternatives would you suggest in order to scroll to a specific index in the flatlist? ScrollView is not an option due to the large amount of data

Comment: I can't have the same behaviour if you added the check and removed the calls to the other scroll function, if this is the case then there is something very wrong with your code elsewhere, plus this should be easily debuggable by checking values and removing code until you find the culprit. If all else fails then you could consider using flatlists scrollToItem() function instead

Comment: you're right, though I can't seem to find where the problem might be as the FlatList is configured correctly. I've created a dummy component with another FlatList and the ref worked perfectly there. I will try it with scrollToItem(), if not then I will need to work on the parent component, I think the problem might be there. Thank you so much for your help and I'll accept your answer as correct!